# bottom layout deprecated since ios 11.0

Tags: autolayout, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9, safearealayoutguide

What can I do to fix Bottom layout is deprecated iOS 11, I am using Xcode 9 beta 2.

[image]

Comment: Weird... I'm not getting errors here https://i.imgur.com/F7dsvP1.png

Answer (score 31):

Simply check the "Use safe area layout guides" button in the File Inspector of the IB.

[image: use safe area layout guides]

Comment: Just to add a little clarity. To fix this in my storyboard file I had to select the storyboard and then the scene in my storyboard to get that option to appear. The option wasn't appearing when I only selected the storyboard. If you have multiple scenes you'll need to do this for each scene in that storyboard file.

Comment: @paper1111 It's ideal to use a red freehand circle: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to

Answer (score 30):

Function of @paper1111 works fine in Xcode Version 9.3.1, but for me not worked first time. After two days of World War with Interface Builder

Solution:

1) **check** the "Use safe area layout guides" button in the File Inspector of the Interface Builder.

2)  **uncheck** the "Use safe area layout guides" button in the File Inspector of the Interface Builder.

3) **check again** the "Use safe area layout guides" button in the File Inspector of the Interface Builder.

4) (a possible additional step) **clean the build folder** In the menu select Product --> Clean Build Folder. Or hold **Shift+Command+K**

Comment: Wow... really a lifesaver!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79400), in iOS 11, IB replaces `bottomLayoutGuide` by `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

> Interface Builder uses [UIView.safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) as a replacement for
>   the deprecated Top and Bottom layout guides in UIViewController. To
>   use the new safe area, select Safe Area Layout Guides in the File
>   inspector for the view controller, and then add constraints between
>   your content and the new safe area anchors. This prevents your content
>   from being obscured by top and bottom bars, and by the overscan region
>   on tvOS. Constraints to the safe area are converted to Top and Bottom
>   when deploying to earlier versions of iOS. (29323293)