# iOS 11 has different autolayout result?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, ios11

I'm using storyboards in this project. I have been searching for the culprit of this layout bug (see photo) and wasn't able to find one. Here are some more detailed information.

1. When debugging the app using my iPhone 7plus iOS 11, I'm using the **Xcode 9.0 Beta 2**.
2. iOS version of the iPhone 7plus is **iOS 11 Beta 9**. As of writing, I'm installing the **Beta 10 of the iOS 11**.
3. I have a side menu library that has a layout bug in my iPhone 7plus (same OS version) too! But when the app is downloaded from the TestFlight or App Store, that layout bug never appears, but in this particular case, the view stays under the tabBar.
4. Layout is perfect in my two devices below iOS 11. It is perfect too in **iPhone 7plus simulator WITH iOS 10.** As of writing, I'm building the project to **iPhone 7plus simulator WITH iOS 11.**
5. I have tried toggling everything in the Interface Builder like under opaque bars, etc...
6. I did add some different colors to some of my views in the storyboard for easier debugging of views using Xcode. And indeed that in iOS 11, the view goes underneath the tabBar while in iOS 10, it does not.

What could be the issue here?

[image]

UPDATE:

- Think of the view in the photo as a plain `UIView`. No scrollView, no tableView. Just a `UIView`, nothing special, not scrollable.

  1. Xcode 9.0 Beta 2's iPhone7plus simulator has a perfect layout.
  2. I have updated my iPhone7plus phone to iOS 11 Beta 10, and layout is still the same.

Comment: Whats the layout bug are you talking about in the photo exactly? Its not a cell but a view??

Comment: Is that a UitableView?

Comment: Added update. New photo. It's just a plain `UIView`. No scrollable stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903413/bottom-layout-deprecated-since-ios-11-0