# topLayoutGuide' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, statusbar

> topLayoutGuide' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    
    IF_IOS7_OR_GREATER
    (
     CGRect frame = _toolbar.frame;
     frame.origin.y = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
     //_toolbar.frame = frame;
     )
}
```

Comment: [Get safe area inset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831519/17771995) This may help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bottom layout deprecated since ios 11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903413/bottom-layout-deprecated-since-ios-11-0)

Comment: What is the question? Clarity is needed.

Comment: What exactly you want to get here? Answer is in question itself.